# Any .Net utility to covert HTML to RTF while maintaining CSS?

Tags: html, .net, rtf

Is there any .Net utility out there that will convert HTML to RTF, which will *also* honour CSS styles? I've found a lot of tripe that will either strip all the styles away, or do a terrible job of presenting them.

There are plenty of HTML to PDF converters out there that do a decent job. I'm surprised it's so difficult to find something to go HTML to RTF.

Please don't reply if you represent sautinsoft. That product falls into the 'terrible' category.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to load a webbrowser with the html, select all, copy and paste into a richtextbox. Then use its `RTF` property.

```
var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
webBrowser.Document.Write("... html...");
webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
richTextBox1.Paste();
```

It's better to use [richtextbox v5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19622958/1543816).

If it's not accurate enough you can use word interop and then paste and copy from a temp word document. I can paste that code from one of my apps if you need it.