# How to dynamically populate RTF documents?

Tags: c#, .net, rtf

Is it possible to create an RTF template document and programmatically insert elements like tables or populate variables? If so, what do I need to do this?

I understand that there is a RichTextBox control that can represent the document, but I need to define a template (or more specifically, the sales guys will be defining the template and giving it to me) which I need to then populate with the data. The RichTextBox control is no good to them. We need RTF because not all clients have Word.

Comment: Shouldn't you update your [former question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543744/any-net-utility-to-covert-html-to-rtf-while-maintaining-css)? I feel both are very similar

Comment: No, one is asking if there's a utility to convert HTML to RTF (which there isn't an answer for). The other is asking how to dynamically populate RTF. They are both about RTF, but they're different questions.

Comment: @DaveDev I'm not going to make this an answer, but I would just go through and replace keywords in the document (e.g. `<%table1%>`, `<%time_submitted%>`) with RTF that was formatted beforehand or `Sytem.DateTime.Now` in the case of the `<%time_submitted%>` example.  I don't know if theres a better way to do it.  Be sure to use `StringBuilder` to cut back a little on the overhead if you do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ToastyMallows suggested, it's come down to a dirty game of replacing strings.

I'm using the following to generate tables and formatting and stuff:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30902/RichText-Builder-StringBuilder-for-RTF

Answer (score 0):

I've done this, but in an old Windows Forms client-side application using Word automation. It works but not elegantly. We defined the templates in WordPad I think, then extracted the RTF which gets stored in a database. There are pre-defined fields that get populated on document creation.

One thing I have discovered in doing RTF stuff, is that the meaning of RichText (the format) and RichText (as in controls) are not necessarily the same.