# Breaks encoding in richtextbox

Tags: c#, encoding, richtextbox

I use richtextbox in my winform application.
When I paste "ជំរាបសួរ Khmer" text all good:

[image]

But when I paste "'مرحب Arabic" text some problems appear: in the first insert having problems with the encoding:

[image]

I have not found any Enсoding properties in richtextbox. How do I solve the problem of encoding?

Comment: Bear in mind that a RichTextBox is basically a RTF container; and a RTF is basically a file which has certain encoding. I have tested your conditions and it happens exactly what you are saying. A priori it seems like this is an unsolvable problem: you can have only one encoding system in a file, when pasting to the RTB, it takes the given encoding automatically; you might change that (for example: by creating a rtf file with the encoding you wish and loading it into the RTB), but your requirements go beyond: two different encodings are required at the same time, what does not seem doable.

Comment: PS: I am saying all this from the tested conditions (by assuming that two different encodings are required at the same time). If there is any encoding able to deal with all the text you want, then you would be able to apply it to the RTB, for example, as suggested: by populating it from a file with the given encoding (I don't mean "physical file", it might be a stream).

Comment: Works fine on my machine, Windows 8.1.  Seeing rectangles is a problem with font substitution, I wouldn't try this on XP.  Writing Khmer and Arabic at the same time is .... unusual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RichTextBox v5. The default in Visual Studio is v4. It fixes this problem among others.

```
public class RichText50W : RichTextBox
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams prams = base.CreateParams;
            if (LoadLibrary("msftedit.dll") != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                prams.ClassName = "RICHEDIT50W";
            }
            return prams;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped to Windows 7, but XP problem remained. Also on XP appeared similar problems with the display of some languages ​​(e.g. Khmer, Hindi, Korean) of treeview and messagebox.